# Captured blurry and different result with the preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend, html2canvas

i'm using html2canvas and canvas2image for my free project. The problem  doesn't seems hard but it makes my brain exploding hhe. Let's check the pictures first :

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIPsJ.jpg | Pic 1
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQcIs.jpg | Pic 2

In `Pic 1` u can see that image seems good. But in `Pic 2` the picture fitted to the div. How do i fix this ?

that's the first question, and the second one is. Why the `div` that captured is blurry ? How do i fix this ?

Third, when i try to download the image, it doesn't show any extension, how do i fix this ?

```
$(function() {
$("#preview").click(function() {
    html2canvas($("#screenshot"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);
            $("#img-preview").append(canvas);
            // Clean up
        }
    });
});
});
```

Thanks..